# Trying to write a script where column h if true would return a value of same row column a to display in email message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Been playing around with this and i am new to this unfortunately. So my goal is if a row in column h is true, in the email message it would get the value of the same row as column h and display what would be column a as the message.

ALL HELP IS THOROUGHLY APPRECIATED

```
function CheckSales() {
  // Fetch the repair scba
  var monthSalesRange =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("H1:H20");
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Check totals sales
  if (monthSales = true) {
    sendEmail();
  }
}

function sendEmail() {
  // Fetch the email address
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("B2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = 'A bottle is in need of repair!'; // Second column
  var subject = 'SCBA Repair Email';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your spreadsheet looks like:

| A | B | ... | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Message to send | Target email address | ... | True/False |

For rows where column H is true, you want to email the message in column A to the user in column B.

If that understanding is correct, this should do the trick:

```
function generateEmails() {
 var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1:H20"); 
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var subject = 'SCBA Repair Email';
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var row = data[i];
   if (row[7]) {
     var recipient = row[1];
     var body = row[0];
     MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  }
 }
}
```